# how to combine two columns into one column having either one of the column

Tags: sql

I have two column in the table

```
column 1     column 2
........     .........
v1           v4
v2           v5
NULL         v6
NULL         v7 
NULL         v8
```

where `v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6` are the values of the column type is varchar
I want to get the output as merged columns but should have only value of the first column

```
column 1
.......
v1 
v2 
v6 
v7 
v8
```

Comment: In Sql Server you can try `SELECT ISNULL(column1, column2) FROM table`.

Comment: Which DBMS? Depending on which one you should use NVL, COALESCE, ISNULL.

Answer (score 7):

Standard SQL is `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(column1,column2) as column1
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case statement

```
select case 
       when t.name is null then t.name2 
                           else t.name 
       end 
from your_table t
```

which should work on most databases. Tested on PostgreSQL.